# How do I sort an array of objects by a subfield?

Tags: sorting, jekyll, liquid

I'm working on a Jekyll site and want to sort the post list on the homepage by `post.date-edit` rather than by `post.date`. However, [it seems like the `sort` filter only works on strings](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/sort/). How do I sort an array of objects by a field in those objects?

Also, so that non-edited posts sort correctly, how do I default to sort by `post.date` if `post.date-edit` isn't present in the front matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an array filter and this should work (not tested and assuming your array name is "posts"):

```
{% assign posts_by_edit = posts | sort: "date-edit" %}
{% for post in posts_by_edit %}
  Do something
{% endfor %}
```